# SFTP dollar sign issue when sending password in Unix

Tags: perl, unix, sed

I need to SFTP a file to a server. The password has a dollar sign `$` and I need to escape it.

I tried with Perl and sed commands I am able to replace but the string following `$` is not getting added.

#### Example:

```
echo "Np4$g" | perl -pe 's/$/\\\\\$/g'
```

#### output

```
Np4\\$
```

It supposed to be `Np4\\$g`, but `g` is not getting appended.

#### Code:

```
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
set timeout -1
spawn sftp -C -oPort=$port $sftp_username@$host_name
expect "password:"
send "$password\r"
expect "sftp>"
cd $remote_dir
send "mput *.txt\r"
expect "sftp>"
send
```

Comment: /usr/bin/expect <<EOF
set timeout -1
spawn sftp -C -oPort=$port $sftp_username@$host_name
expect "password:"
send "$password\r"
expect "sftp>"
cd $remote_dir
send "mput *.txt\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "quit\r"
EOF

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 2):

Your command

```
echo "Np4$g" | perl -pe 's/$/\\\\\$/g'
```

is failing for two reasons

- In `"Np4$g"`, the shell is interpolating the variable `g` into the double-quoted string. It probably isn't defined so it is replaced with nothing, and you are passing just `Np4` to perl. You need to use single quotes to prevent the interpolation
- In the Perl substitution `s/$/\\\\\$/g` the `$` in the pattern matches the end of the string, not a literal dollar. That means  `Np4` is changed to `Np4\\$`. You need to escape the dollar sign in the pattern to get it to match a literal `$`

This will work correctly

```
echo 'Np4$g' | perl -pe 's/\$/\\\$/g'
```

#### output

```
Np4\$g
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to not escape and replace

```
"Np4$g"
```

by

```
'Np4$g'
```